# Showing last entry as first PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display last entry as first and tried to use it as array but not able to get it, here is the code I have:

```
<?php
$maxItem = 30;
for ($i=1; $i<$maxItem + 1; $i++) {
    if (have_rows('content_block_'.$i)) {
        while (have_rows('content_block_'.$i)) {
        the_row();
?>
```

Current Output

```
<div class="content_block_1">1</div>
<div class="content_block_2">2</div>
<div class="content_block_3">3</div>
<div class="content_block_4">4</div>
```

Expected Output

```
<!-- if new entry -->
<div class="content_block_5">5</div>
<div class="content_block_1">1</div>
<div class="content_block_2">2</div>
<div class="content_block_3">3</div>
<div class="content_block_4">4</div>
```

Comment: tried looping from 30 to 1?

Comment: I did not, is it good to try that way?

Comment: 1 + 10 or 10 + 1, which one is good ?

Comment: Makes no difference !!

Comment: tried but its reversing the entries, what I am looking for not to change the existing entry but to show first as last entered item.

Comment: please add the expected output and the current output you're getting !!

Comment: @SanjeevKumar What does `have_rows('content_block_'.$i)` do? If you do `have_rows('content_block_'.$$maxItem)`, does it return highest value rows?

Comment: have_rows('content_block_'.$i) counting the next field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$maxItem = 30;
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxItem; $i++) {
    $block_item = $i == 0 ? $maxItem : $i;
    while (have_rows('content_block_'.$block_item)) {
        the_row();
    }
}
```

You can simply check if value of `$i` is `0`. If yes, go for the last entry, i.e,
`$maxItem`, otherwise, complete the rest of it sequentially.